# Are there any security definitions for DNS?

Tags: security-definition

Given a [recent post on the Tor blog](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/cooking-onions-names-your-onions) and the [corresponding discussion on HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14038013) I was wondering if there are any security definitions for DNS or similar name systems.

So something similar to ACCE for TLS but for DNS.

Or at least a more structured treatment of security of name systems.